# How to Find the File's Owner in Xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode

this might seem like a stupid question, but I am a newbie on Xcode. While trying to run my simulator, my app crashed. Searching on here for a solution, I found this answer:

Ctrl-/right-click on the File's Owner in the Xcode editor, look for a warning triangle. Clear that out (by deleting the connection or re-connecting it to the proper outlet) and you'll likely be good.

I have no idea where this is! If you can include visuals, I would appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: You probably have stray connections. You can select your view object and on the right sidebar, click the last tab (connections tab).

Comment: View object? Sorry I am not familiar with these terms yet!

Comment: Well I posted a new question which may give you my problem in more detail. Thanks for the help btw!